# bootstrap grid not working inside of elements

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a button group that is going to have 3 buttons per row. My buttons are regular bootstrap buttons with images for icons. I have a grid inside of the button using spans but the icon image gets pushed out of the column.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6>
           <div class="row">
                 <div class="btn-group order-type-buttons col-12" 
                 role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4"><span class="col-8 button-text">Online Pick Up</span><span class="col-4 span-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/online-pickup-icon.png" alt=""></span></button>
    <button type="button" role="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4"><span class="col-8 button-text">Online Take out</span><span class="col-4 span-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/online-take-out-icon.png" alt=""></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4"><span class="col-8 button-text">Pick up</span><span class="col-4 span-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/pick-up-icon.png" alt=""></span></button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group order-type-buttons col-12" role="group" aria-label="second group">
    <button  type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4"><span class="col-8 button-text">Refund</span><span class="col-4 span-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/refund-icon.png" alt=""></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4"><span class="col-8 button-text">Room Service</span><span class="col-4 span-img"><img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon%20files/room-service-icon.png" alt=""></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn order-type-btn-blue col-4"><span class="col-8 button-text">Take</span><span class="col-4 span-img"><img class="img-fluid rounded" src="images/icon%20files/take-out-icon.png" alt=""></span></button>
</div>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-text{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.order-type-btn-blue{
    background-color: #0082d5;
    font-size:14px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.order-type-buttons {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.span-img{
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

How the buttons look on my page:

[image: How Buttons look on page]

Comment: please add the your images also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a block element instead of `span`, an inline element, hence margin, overflow, and some other functionality on span won't work as it would with `div`. To align content on the same row and center horizontally, use `d-flex justify-content-center`, to center it vertically, use `align-items-center`. Use `text-truncate` to prevent overflow and add '...' at the end of the text. Use `text-uppercase` to transform text into uppercase.  Hope it would help!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-12 d-flex">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-toggle="button">
      <div class="col-8 text-uppercase">Online Pick Up</div>
      <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></div>
    </button>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-toggle="button">
      <div class="col-8 text-uppercase">Online Take Out</div>
      <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></div>
    </button>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-toggle="button">
      <div class="col-8 text-truncate text-uppercase">Online Something Text Pick Up</div>
      <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt=""></div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the assigned `display` property of `.row`s is `flex`, it's irrelevant if one uses either `<div>` of `<span>` for either `.row` or `.col`. The outcome is the same. The problem here is that OP is **not** using `.row`s as containers for `.col`s, as [documented here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). That thing is not optional. If you don't use it, it won't work as designed.

Comment: I don't see how it's irrelevant if one uses either <div> or <span> as it'd give different results. As given in your example, if you add a long (overflowing) text, in each case, although it's probably not going to push the image out of the box, it'd behave differently.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Because of `display:flex` on the parent. That's what I'm trying to tell you. But you don't have to believe me. Feel free to provide a valid Bootstrap grid example where using `<span>` instead of `<div>` for either `.row` or `.col` makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay more attention to Bootstrap's markup (HTML). If you don't, it doesn't work as expected.

The definition of a Bootstrap "grid" is that it **has to have** the class `row` and immediate descendants have class(es) of type `col-*`. In simple words, columns must be wrapped in rows. If you don't respect this, you shouldn't expect it to perform as designed.

If you want to further divide a `.col-*` element you need to place a `.row` element inside of it and place other smaller `.col-*`s inside that `.row`.

Also, your big (layout) `.row`s should be direct descendants of a `.container` or `.container-fluid`, you can have `.container`s inside `.container-fluid`s but you can't have `.container`s inside `.container`s.

If you look closely at all of the above *"rules"*, they are respected by all their examples but they are not clearly specified anywhere. However, if you take the time to look at what each of those classes apply, in terms of CSS rules, they make perfect sense.

Example:

```css
.order-type-buttons > .btn:not(#_){
    font-size:14px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.order-type-buttons > .btn > span {
display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.button-text.col {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
.span-img img {
  margin: -7px 0;
  height: 5rem;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="btn-group d-flex order-type-buttons" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="row align-items-center no-gutters w-100">
            <span class="col button-text">Online Pick Up</span>
            <span class="col span-img d-block">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/007bff/fff" alt="">
            </span>
          </span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="row align-items-center no-gutters w-100">
            <span class="col button-text">Online Take out</span>
            <span class="col span-img d-block">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/120x80/007bff/fff" alt="">
            </span>
          </span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="row align-items-center no-gutters w-100">
            <span class="col button-text">Pick up</span>
            <span class="col span-img d-block">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x360/007bff/fff" alt="">
            </span>
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note `.btn` applies `white-space: nowrap` to all its descendants, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Sorry about that. this element is an angular component and I didn't include the parent container divs. I made the correction.

Comment: You still have `.col-*`s as direct children of `.col-*`s. Please read carefully.